# How can I remove the last 3 commits and restage the changes?

Tags: git

I have committed a file >100MB (github's limit) 3 commits ago, and it won't let me push my new commits.

I want to delete those 3 commits while keeping my work, so I can re-commit them, but without the massive file.

What's the easiest way?

PS I only have access to git command line.

Comment: Did you push the commit to a remote repository? If not and the 3 changes are local you could do a [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: Read the below answer and use the BFG to clean your repo.

Comment: Once you remove the files use this : https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full information can be found in this post:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

The best option is to do something which is not desrivbed there,

```
git reset HEAD --mixed HEAD^3
```

It will checkout the 3rd commit and use the above post to continue working from this point on.

Follow the checkout as its described there:

#### `git checkout`

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit.
This command will checkout to a given commit.
At this point you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit. 
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
#in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash, in your case 6
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `e` for edit the commit.

[image]

---

If you just want to remove big files from the repo use this:
You should use this tool:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

It the prefect tool for this kind of task

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

Comment: won't this erase all my work in those 3 commits in folder?

Comment: Nope, if you checkout and then create a new branch from it they will still be there and you can later on do a git rebase -i  to edit the commit.

Comment: You shouldn't have just posted `git reset --hard HEAD^3` on its own before you edited your post - that does delete OPs three most recent, un-pushed commits.

Comment: Or, you can `git reset --mixed HEAD~3` to reset the index but leave your working tree (actual visible files) alone. Then, just add and re-push only the files you actually want.

Comment: @user234461 No, it doesn't _delete_ anything, it just updates the working copy to reflect that commit.  You can immediately reset back to the previous HEAD and everything will still be there.

Comment: I agree and did a downvote even when this will do the PO asked for :-(

Comment: Looks like `git reset --mixed HEAD~3` was the right answer, thanks @Useless!

Comment: It was, since reset doesn not delete commits, you can always do a git cherry-pick to add them back.

Comment: Updating the answer to be more correct with the --mixed instead of the --hard

Comment: Glad to help, read the comments under your question, i posted some helpfull inks for you,